# Application can not start on Samsung Galaxy Tab SII

Tags: java, android, samsung-mobile

I have worked many projects with no problems. But in current project, I tested on Samsung Galaxy Tab (GT-P7300), the application cannot start. The screen flash when I run it, then exit to home immediately (no force close message, the home screen just immediately pops out). The LogCat show these errors:

```
03-14 16:18:41.060: E/AndroidRuntime(4144): Set to default setting_6 : region=-Duser.region=US propRegn=US
03-14 16:18:41.070: E/AndroidRuntime(4144): /system/csc/feature.xml ==> cannot open file
03-14 16:18:41.340: E/AndroidRuntime(4154): Set to default setting_6 : region=-Duser.region=US propRegn=US
03-14 16:18:41.360: E/AndroidRuntime(4154): /system/csc/feature.xml ==> cannot open file
```

> Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred. Channel is
>   unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!

Other message from LogCat:

```
03-14 15:16:40.370: E/TODmobile(650): onReceive action=sec.android.intent.action.HOME_RESUME
03-14 15:16:40.380: E/TODmobile(650): hour : 15    minute : 16
03-14 15:16:40.380: E/DigitalClockWidget(650): updateWidgets
03-14 15:16:40.410: E/TODmobile(650): hour : 15    minute : 16
03-14 15:16:40.450: E/DigitalClockWidget(650): onReceive action=sec.android.intent.action.HOME_RESUME
03-14 15:16:40.450: E/TODmobile(650): onStartCommand
03-14 15:16:40.450: E/TODmobile(650): onReceive action=com.sec.android.widgetapp.DigitalClock_Start
03-14 15:16:40.460: E/TODmobile(650): hour : 15    minute : 16
03-14 15:16:40.460: E/DigitalClockWidget(650): updateWidgets
03-14 15:16:40.510: E/TODmobile(650): hour : 15    minute : 16
03-14 15:16:40.980: E/TODmobile(650): onReceive action=sec.android.intent.action.HOME_RESUME
03-14 15:16:41.010: E/TODmobile(650): hour : 15    minute : 16
03-14 15:16:41.010: E/DigitalClockWidget(650): updateWidgets
03-14 15:16:41.010: E/TODmobile(650): hour : 15    minute : 16
03-14 15:16:41.030: E/DigitalClockWidget(650): onReceive action=sec.android.intent.action.HOME_RESUME
03-14 15:16:41.030: E/TODmobile(650): onStartCommand
03-14 15:16:41.040: E/TODmobile(650): onReceive action=com.sec.android.widgetapp.DigitalClock_Start
03-14 15:16:41.050: E/TODmobile(650): hour : 15    minute : 16
03-14 15:16:41.060: E/DigitalClockWidget(650): updateWidgets
03-14 15:16:41.060: E/TODmobile(650): hour : 15    minute : 16
03-14 15:16:41.410: E/DigitalClockWidget(650): onReceive action=com.sec.android.widgetapp.APPWIDGET_RESIZE
03-14 15:16:41.410: E/TODmobile(650): onStartCommand
03-14 15:16:41.420: E/TODmobile(650): onReceive action=com.sec.android.widgetapp.DigitalClock_Start
03-14 15:16:41.420: E/TODmobile(650): hour : 15    minute : 16
03-14 15:16:41.420: E/DigitalClockWidget(650): updateWidgets
03-14 15:16:41.420: E/TODmobile(650): hour : 15    minute : 16
03-14 15:16:41.570: E/RemoteViews(362): Cannot setOnClickPendingIntent for collection item (id: 2131755055)
03-14 15:16:41.570: E/RemoteViews(362): Cannot setOnClickPendingIntent for collection item (id: 2131755055)
```

The program works well on LG GT540 and Samsung Ace.

What is causing this problem? I searched the error message and found a lot of people encountered it, but there is no clear solution.

EDIT: More information, I tried on Galaxy Tab (GT-P1000, running Android 2.3.3), it works well too. And when I try it on Android SDK Emulator with a 3.0 device, the program also flash then disappear. So only Android 3.0 (maybe also 4.0) throws this problem.

Comment: Sure you don't have more information in the log?

Comment: @DavidOlsson Just added more. I think it's not important.

Comment: Tell me more about your application W.N. What does it actually do?

Comment: Have you localized your app like here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html. Then you could change your phone's language and watch if something happened.You should also remove your values-us folder and watch if something is happening.

Comment: Hmm, I don't know why, but today it suddenly runs my program, although I didn't change much thing, just at my algorithm (only execute after user input), everything else such as layouts, resources, assets, ... stay the same. I don't change any phone setting too.

Comment: I saw similar behavior of some apps if there were no enough free space in internal memory, however that is unlikely applicable for the emulator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like a. ch said, I also have seen this with not enough memory issues, also packages having been left installed with the same package id, and even if the graphics are needing to be resized. With that said:

If you are [supporting multiple screens](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) I would ensure there are graphics in each MDPI, HDPI, XHDPI respectively, and that they are [optimized](http://trimage.org/) and set to the [appropriate DPI](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#qualifiers). That should ensure all devices and API levels play nice.

Even if that isn't the root of your problem, it is good to ensure for best practices when it comes to performance and reliability.

Comment: Now you mention it, I remembered. In previous unsuccessful builds, I delete `hdpi`, `ldpi` and `mdpi` folders, and use a single `drawable` folder.